# Solr - No Results W/ Some Searches

Tags: solr, magento

We recently switched the search index for our company websites over to Solr and while, in most cases, we are getting much more relevant results, we are getting some odd behavior that I can't figure out.

For example: If you search for the term Painted Wooden Horse Shapes it returns a number of results, all relevant. If you search for Wooden Painted Horse or any permutation other than the first search in that exact order, it returns no results.

I have messed extensively with the schema.xml file and worked on index modifications but cannot figure out why this happens, nor how to remedy it. Any tips/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely the text analysis is misconfigured. Please post your schema.xml

Comment: you may have string types for that field when you should have text types, that would explain why "Exact Match" would show up but not Match Exact